# Is there an easy way to store and reload observeEvents in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I create callbacks dynamically during the life of an shiny app. I want to be able to store them into an RDS and then later reload them. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn1","Btn1"),
  actionButton("btn2","Btn2"),
  actionButton("btn3","Btn3"),
  actionButton("btn4","Btn4"),
  actionButton("btn5","Btn5"),
  actionButton("btn6","Btn6"),
  actionButton("btn7","Btn7"),
  hr(),
  actionButton("makeCallbacks","Make Callbacks"),
  actionButton("saveCallbacks", "Save Callbacks"),
  actionButton("loadCallbacks", "Load callbacks"),
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observerList <- list()
  observeEvent(input$makeCallbacks, {
    observerList <<- lapply(1:7, function(i){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("btn",i)]],{
        print(i)
      },
      label = paste0("Event for Button ", i))
    })
  })
  observeEvent(input$saveCallbacks, {
    saveRDS(observerList, "observerList.RDS")
  })
  observeEvent(input$loadCallbacks, {
    ol <- readRDS("observerList.RDS")
    observerList <<- lapply(ol, function(o){o})
    print(observerList)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server, options = list("launch.browser"=TRUE))
```

You start the app for the very first time, click on "makeCallbacks" and then "saveCallbacks".

Now you close the app and instead of clicking "makeCallbacks" you just click "loadCallbacks". The observerList is correct, but unfortunately the callbacks do not work.

In my real app the callbacks are not always the same so it makes more sense to save and load them...

Comment: `observeEvent` does not return a callback. It returns an observer reference class object.  You can't call the output of `observeEvent` because its not a function.

Comment: @Noskario: same as SmokeyShakers. But what do you want really to save ? Could you you elaborate the description of your need. Maybe you want to save the value of the `input`s in fact ? Perhaps you could make intermediate `reactive()` data's to be used as  `eventExpr` events of `ObserveEvent()` and save these datas ?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use reactive, since the observeEvents listen to actionButtons. I have an app where you first divide your data into groups and then have the possibility to refine groups. And in case you delete a group (using an actionButton) it depends a lot of context wether the elements in the group go back into the original group where they come from or to some kind of rest-group. That is the reason I wanted to reuse the observeEvents I have already written.